# Showing bingmap on popup

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am  using this code to show a usercontrol in popup.

```
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <map:Map  Width="450" x:Name="Map" CredentialsProvider="map credential"  >
            <map:Map.Mode>
                <map:RoadMode />
            </map:Map.Mode>
            <map:Pushpin x:Name="Pin" Style="{StaticResource PushpinControlTemplateBlue1}"   IsHitTestVisible="True" IsEnabled="True">
                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragDelta="Pushpin_OnDragDelta" DragStarted="Pushpin_OnDragStarted" DragCompleted="Pushpin_OnDragCompleted">
                    </toolkit:GestureListener>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <map:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform></TranslateTransform>
                </map:Pushpin.RenderTransform>
            </map:Pushpin>
        </map:Map>

    </Grid>
```

When I try the same code for a page, map is displayed but for the popup, the map is not shown.

Can anyone help me out for this.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't show Bing Maps in a popup. It's a very heavy control, and requires a lot of interaction.

If you really want to show a map, you should show a static image from the Bing Maps web-service, or lock the control down entirely, so it don't support user interaction.

Generally you should avoid using popup's on Windows Phone, it provides a bad user experience. Use a [BingMapsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394026%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) instead to show a given location with the phone's build-in map system.